# Pig filter not working

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have the following pig script,

```
meta_file = LOAD 'meta_file' USING PigStorage(',');

DUMP meta_file;

meta = FOREACH meta_file GENERATE (chararray)$0 AS is_vta:chararray, (chararray)$1 AS id:long;

DUMP meta;

new_d = FILTER meta BY (is_vta == 't');
DUMP new_d;
```

Contents of `meta_file`:

```
"t","7181397"
"t","6331589"
"f","7266217"
"t","6051440"
"t","6901437"
"t","6805292"
"f","7144764"
"t","6820265"
"f","7515321"
"t","4777938"
```

DUMP of `meta_file` is exactly fine and is same as the contents of file, so are the contents of meta, but `new_d` is empty. I can see that there are `is_vta` in `meta` with values `t`, but still `new_d` is empty. Why isn't meta getting filtered properly? What am I doing wrong here? I am new to Pig Latin and am not able to figure out what might be the problem here.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Can you try new_d = FILTER meta BY (is_vta == '"t"'); ?

Comment: @dltu Yes, quotes were causing problem. `is_vta == '"t"'` as well as removing quotes from file itself worked. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple way:

```
new_d = FILTER meta BY is_vta MATCHES '.*t.*';
```

another solution:

```
remquotes = FOREACH meta GENERATE REPLACE($0, '\\"', '') AS is_vta:chararray, id;

new_d = FILTER remquotes BY is_vta == 't';
```

Comment: Yes, quotes were causing problem. `is_vta == '"t"'` as well as removing quotes from file itself worked. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

I think quotes are causing problem: two ways to handle them here

1: use piggybank to handle quotes: rest your quote should work.

```
REGISTER 'piggybank.jar'  -- > this jar handles quotes by default. 

A = LOAD 'fil.csv'  using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(',') as (---Your Schema --- );
```

or 
2:

use regex and trim quotes. 
[Remove single quotes from data using Pig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29119557/remove-single-quotes-from-data-using-pig)

Comment: Yes, quotes were causing problem. `is_vta == '"t"'` as well as removing quotes from file itself worked. Thanks for the help :)